# Add items to my list using Google Assistant

Tags: android, android-intent, google-assistant-sdk

I have a shopping list app and I want to create a new list and add items to the app using voice on Google Assistant as below image.

There are [intents](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/actions/ItemListIntents) that are supposed to add items to a list.

How can I implement them? And associate "create a list" to my app?

[image]

PS: On iOS, I used Sirikit with the intents: INCreateTaskListIntent, INAddTasksIntent and INSetTaskAttributeIntent

Comment: can you provide more info for clarity of question.

Comment: @PragatiSingh I did like this on iOS: https://martinmitrevski.com/2017/06/24/creating-lists-with-sirikit-on-ios11/
And I want to do the same on Android using google assistant. I have the same app on Android and iOS.

Comment: @yasin Did you created it?